# specific 4 inch drawable layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to design a specific layout for galaxy S3 mini or any device with 4 inch screen size, now I don't want to use normal-layout because what looks perfect in other devices in normal-layout looks messy in 4 inch devices, I tried to do a layout for 480 x 800 like layout-w480dp-h800dp but it didn't work so what specific layout can I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best answer is to fix your UI to not look "messy" on a "device with 4 inch screen size". A 4" diagonal screen is right in the middle of the `-normal` range, and therefore if your design does not work on a 4" diagonal screen, your `-normal` UI is simply broken.